# react-redux-firebase: uid undefined in realtime database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux-firebase

I was trying to setup react-redux-firebase in my project with user profiles as described in [the docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/auth.html). I ran into the following problem - everytime I created a user, the database would save the user data under "undefined":

[image: firebase data]

I assume it's supposed to save the users under their uid, so for some reason the uid is undefined when the user is stored in the database. I created a sandbox that reproduces the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/6jl07r6v7w
(paste your own firebase config into store.js to try it out for yourself).

Here's how I set up the store:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, compose } from "redux";
import { reactReduxFirebase, firebaseReducer } from "react-redux-firebase";
import firebase from "firebase";

export const initStore = () => {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    // config
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const rrfConfig = {
    userProfile: "users"
  };

  const createStoreWithFirebase = compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig)
  )(createStore);

  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    firebase: firebaseReducer
  });

  return createStoreWithFirebase(rootReducer);
};
```

and here's where I create the user:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";

class CreateUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  submit() {
    this.props.firebase
      .createUser({
        email: "test@test.com",
        password: "123456"
      })
      .then(userData => console.log(userData))
      .catch(err => window.alert(err.message));
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.submit}>create a user</button>;
  }
}

export default withFirebase(CreateUser);
```

Looks just like in the docs to me. Anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `5.*.*` of the Firebase JS SDK?

If so, this may be due to some breaking changes in the recent Firebase JS SDK release, which impacted some of of `react-redux-firebase` handles profiles ([believe this recently reported issue is the same](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/468)).

Currently working on a fix for this, but as always open to PRs if you get a chance.

Disclosure: I am a main author of [react-redux-firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/468)

Comment: Great to hear. Just a heads up, [v2.1.4](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/releases/tag/v2.1.4) fixes support for `v5.*.*` Firebase JS SDK.